# Twitter4j gather only a certain country

Tags: api, stream, twitter4j

for a project I am currently working on I need to gather tweets from a stream only for one country. 
Although the Twitter4j streaming API allows to filter by language the results aren't accurate enough. So I thought to put a filter on top of the filter by checking if the country attribute of the tweet is filled. This works fine when I check if theres a value at all:

```
if(status.getPlace().getCountry() != null) {
            System.out.println("User: " + status.getUser().getName());
            System.out.println("Text: : " + status.getText());
            System.out.println("Country: " + status.getPlace().getCountry());
            System.out.println("Language: " + status.getLang());
            }
        }

    TwitterStream ts = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
    ts.addListener(listener);

    FilterQuery filter = new FilterQuery(); 

    String[] language = {"country"};
    String[] keywords = {"some keywords"}; 

    filter.track(keywords);
    filter.language(language); 

    ts.filter(filter);
```

But if I check for a certain country e.g. germany I don't receive any tweets:

```
if(status.getPlace().getCountry() != "germany") {
            System.out.println("User: " + status.getUser().getName());
            System.out.println("Text: : " + status.getText());
            System.out.println("Country: " + status.getPlace().getCountry());
            System.out.println("Language: " + status.getLang());
            }
        }
```

It would be great if there's someone who can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
filter.track(keywords);
filter.language(language);
```

Keep in mind that the above code means `track(keywords)` OR `language(language)`.
This is not logical AND.

If you want tweets from only one country, and with certain keywords, then remove `filter.language(language)` and check the country after you get status.

```
if(status.getPlace().getCountry().equalsIgnoreCase("germany")) {}
```

// String comparison

You won't get a tweet from Germany if nobody from Germany tweets with the filters you have specified.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. 
I removed the language filter to track only by keywords. 
What do you mean by "after you get status"? I'm checking for germany in the onStatus method.
But the problem still remains. I still get no tweets even if I specify only some characters as keywords like "a, b, c, d, etc."
And of course I mean "==". My fault ;)

Comment: I meant onStatus method. `if(status.getLang().equalsIgnoreCase("lang") && status.getPlace().getCountry().equalsIgnoreCase("germany")) {}`

Comment: String comparison using `==` was the problem